# Python: Problem in implementing dilate method

Tags: python, opencv

The method takes the original image and elem filer.
For dilation, the new center pixel value is 1/255 if any of the overlapping input pixel values is 1/255.
The method I wrote below goes through every pixel and sets the filtered center to 255 if any overlapping is found.
However, I end up getting a big white square.

I think I got something wrong with this line:
output[i + ((eCol-1)//2), j+((eRow-1)//2)] = 255.
replace it with ' output[i+m,j+n] = 255 ' will make no change to original image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Mat I, Mat elem
#the new center pixel value is 1 if any of the overlapping input pixel values is 1.
def Dilate(I, elem):
    # TODO
    iCol = I.shape[0];
    iRow = I.shape[1];

    eRow = elem.shape[0]
    eCol = elem.shape[1]
    
    row = iRow - eRow + 1
    col = iCol - eCol + 1
    output=I
    
    #print (eCol)
    #print (eRow)
    for i in range(0, col):
        for j in range(0, row):

            for m in range (0, eCol):
                for n in range (0, eRow):
                    
                    if I[i+m,j+n] == elem[m][n] == 1:
                        output[i+(eCol-1)//2, j+(eRow-1)//2] = 1
                    elif I[i+m,j+n] == 255 and elem[m][n] == 1:
                        output[i + ((eCol-1)//2), j+((eRow-1)//2)] = 255    
    return output

# test.bmp is a binary or black and white image
I = cv.imread("test.bmp", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

elem1= np.array( 
        [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

DilateI = Dilate(I,elem1)

output = cv.cvtColor(DilateI, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

[image: original img]
[image: failed img]
[image: demo]

Comment: What did you expect to get instead?

Comment: If you're using NumPy matrices, then operate on them as a whole using broadcasting instead of iterating through them element by element!

Comment: @MattDMo Hi, if I replace output[i + ((eCol-1)//2), j+((eRow-1)//2)] = 255 with ' output[i+m,j+n] = 255 ' will make no change to original image. I don't think it's numpy issue.

Comment: One of the problems that I see in your code is this line "output=I", this means that as you write output, your input array also gets modified. Try output=I.copy(), that might just solve your problem. No promises though.

Comment: @Knight Forked OMG, Thank you, man! It totally solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Knight Forked's comment, I did not have any computation error in the method, but it is because I assign 'output' to I's address directly.
Change the output = I to output = I.copy() will solve the problem I had earlier.

```
# output = I 
output = I.copy()
```

I think the problem happened because every time I compute output, it refers to I's address instead of output itself.